# Ontop Plugin in Protege 5.5.0 create graph using database data

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, protege, knowledge-graph

I connected the database in protege through **Ontop Plugin** and created Mapping from **Ontop Mappings / Mapping Manager**

Now I am creating a graph using that mapping from Ontop Mapping but I m not able to use database table values.
However, I created a database relation mapping graph through **OWLViz**.

[OWLViz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlmvD.png)

I want to create a graph using table data using multiple inner join queries, but I don't know how to use ontop mapping for the same

[SPARQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zZ6f.png)

Comment: you have to show the Ontop mappings here. Also, did you connect Ontop to the relation database?

Answer (score 0):

Have to try to connect your DB with the Ontop plugin in protege?

You have to set Ontop Mapping IDs for creating a graph using SPARQL Query.